# Oracle Form 6i opening word document

Tags: ms-office, ole, oracleforms

We have a program built in Oracle Forms 6i by someone else. There's a function in the form that when the button is click, the form will call to open a MS Word template and put the data in the database into the template.  Now that we migrated to Windows 7 and Office 10, the template no longer opened in MS Words by the Oracle Forms. There is no error... Here is the code that is used to start up MS Words:

```
procedure fileopen (fname in varchar2) is
  arglist ole2.list_type;
begin  
   obj_hnd := ole2.create_obj ('Word.Basic');

  arglist := ole2.create_arglist;
  ole2.add_arg (arglist, fname);
  ole2.invoke (obj_hnd, 'fileopen', arglist);
  ole2.invoke(obj_hnd, 'AppShow');
  ole2.destroy_arglist (arglist);
end;
```

Does anyone have an idea why the MS word is not starting up? What should I look into to fix the problem? There is no problem when the form is run under Windows XP with MS Words 2003.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using Word.Basic in your code.

I think you should use Word.Application instead.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that but nothing is happening when I change from Word.Basic to Word.Application